# Building Magento online vs Download and building locally

Tags: installation, development

I see that Magento can be downloaded and your store can be developed locally and then uploaded or you can develop it online using softaculous to install it.

I want to know if there any advantage/disadvantage of choosing one over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I've worked only on local versions of Magento but I can tell you that upgrading is sometimes a pain in the butt so having it on the cloud is most likely is better.